# Unable to set a global variable in postman from response body(Mostly an Array). Assertion error is thrown

Tags: postman, global-variables

I m trying to set a global variable from a response JSON. Here is the response:

```
[
    {
        "memberDetails": [
            {
                "MemberId": "37e32af1-99a1-49b1-441d-08d9c636b242",
                "AccountId": "9c8041df-6bf4-404e-9360-690280d627dc",
                "Status": 1
            }
                         ]
    }
]
```

**The code I am using under tests**

```
pm.test("Verify Response code", function() { 
    pm.response.to.have.status(data.ExpectedResult)
});

var jsonData = pm.response.json();

    if(pm.response.code === 200) {
        pm.test("Verify MemberId is present when response code is 200", function() {
        pm.expect(jsonData).to.have.property("MemberId")
        postman.setGlobalVariable("SedMemberId", jsonData['MemberId'])
    });
    }else{
        pm.test("Verify MemberID is not present when response code is not 200", function() {
        pm.expect(jsonData).to.not.have.property("MemberId");
    });
}
```

But I am getting the following two errors:

1. Verify Response code | AssertionError: expected response to have status reason undefined but got 'OK'
2. Verify MemberId is present when response code is 200 | AssertionError: expected [ { memberDetails: [ [Object] ] } ] to have property 'MemberId'

How do I set the global variable "SedMemberID" with value "MemberID" in the response JSON.

Answer (score 1):

You're not referencing the response data correctly:

```
pm.globals.set('sedMemberId', jsonData[0].memberDetails[0].MemberId);
```

You might need to take a look at how to reference different object items of JSON structures when they contain arrays.

Not sure what `data.expectedResult` is but it's not going to be defined unless you use a datafile. Even then, you should be using `pm.iterationData.get('key_name')`.

Comment: Thank you Danny. Your inputs helped me fix one of the errors(second one). Extracting data from the array issue is fixed. However I did not follow the second part. What should be the keyname here. Can you please elaborate. I am still getting the first error mentioned in my initial question.

Comment: Where did you get this code from? If you don't understand what the test is checking, why have it there. That looks like it's reading that `data.expectedResult` value from a datafile, if you don't know anything about that, I suspect you didn't write this code.

Comment: Sure thank you. Will remove it from the code. Yeah this was an existing code. Thanks for your reponses @danny dainton

Comment: It would just be that `pm.response.to.have.status('OK')`